# Dimensions of Matrices Range (equalities).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I’d like to find range equalities.
Considering the following:
$$
A=B+C \\
A=B.C^T \\
A=[  B^T  C^T ]^T \\
$$
I would like to find the function $f$ for each equality above.
$$
\dim( R(A) ) = f( R(B) ,  R(C) )
$$
Consider that all matrices have compatible dimensions.
Can you help me?

I sincerely thank you!

All the best

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol $R(\cdot)$? Range (i.e. image)?

Comment: Hi user1551, Yes it means range or column space. you could replace it by the symbols C(.) or Im(.). Thank you, All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

No such formulae exist in general. For a counterexamples, let
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
Z=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

1. Consider $(A,B,C)=(X+Z,X,Z),(Y+Z,Y,Z)$. $R(B)$ and $R(C)$ remain the same in both cases, but $\dim R(X+Z)=2\neq1=\dim R(Y+Z)$.
2. Consider $(A,B,C)=(XY,X,Y^T),(Y^2,Y,Y^T)$. $R(B)$ and $R(C)$ remain the same in both cases, but $\dim R(XY)=1\neq0=\dim R(Y^2)$.
3. Consider $(A,B,C)=(XZ,Z,X),(YZ,Z,Y)$. $R(B)$ and $R(C)$ remain the same in both cases, but $\dim R(XZ)=0\neq1=\dim R(YZ)$.

Comment: And what about $\dim(R(A))=\dim(R(B))+\dim(R(C))-\dim(R(B) \cap R(C))$ for the first equation?

Comment: The LHS of your alleged equality is $\dim R(A)\equiv\dim R(B+C)$, while the RHS is $\dim (R(B)+R(C))$. The two are not equal in general. See my answer for a counterexample.

Comment: I'm confused with your answer because its strange. you cannot sum up two ranges since they are sets. Could you explain a little bit? by the way this expression is in a paper and it has been confirmed.

Comment: When we talk about the range of a linear map, we don't mean the range/codomain of a function, but the image of the linear map, which is a vector subspace. The sum of two vector subspaces $V$ and $W$ is defined by $V+W=\{v+w: v\in V,\,w\in W\}$. For finite dimensional vector subspaces, we have the [formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Sum_and_Intersection_of_Vector_Spaces) $\dim(V+W)=\dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap W)$. If you put $V=R(B)$ and $W=R(C)$, you will see that the RHS of your alleged equality is $\dim(R(B)+R(C))$, which, as I said, is in general different from your LHS.

Comment: BTW, my answer does **not** involve sums of vector subspaces. You may go throught it to see why your required function $f$ does not exist and why your alleged equality is false.

Comment: I see your point but I'm not summing up vectors spaces  as you defined above. Besides, I asked R(B+C) and not R(B)+R(C) which are not the same.Perhaps you could give an example of matrices A,B and C that makes that equality false. I really would appreciate All the best GoodSpirit

Comment: Of course you are asking about $R(B+C)$ and not $R(B)+R(C)$, and *that* is what I kept talking about! The LHS of your dimension equality is $\dim R(B+C)$ (that's OK), but the RHS is **not** $\dim R(B+C)$: it's $\dim(R(B)+R(C))$. So the two sides are not equal in general. The equality is simply wrong. And I don't understand why you keep asking me to give a counterexample to your alleged equality. I have told you twice that a counterexample had been given in my answer: take $(A,B,C)=(Y+Z,Y,Z)$ for the $Y$ and $Z$ in my answer; then your alleged equality gives a wrong result $1 = 1 + 1 - 0$.